# I want to get the recyclerview in order

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am constructing a recyclerview using retrofit I want to take the order from retrofit's response and show the recyclerview in that order but I can't find a way even after searching what can I try?
It is enough to simply list the texts in the order of the data values ​​received from the response.

Comment: Please show your code. Show what you have got so far. Are you managed to create a recyclerview with the data not in order?

Comment: An `ArrayList` is ordered by insertion. The order in which you receive the responses is the order in which it will be added to the `ArrayList`. An `ArrayList` is the standard backing list of a `RecyclerView.Adapter` you should have everything you need. Unless you are referring to something else?

Comment: Nothing has been added yet. I get the order of the lists to be displayed in the recycler view with retrofit and I want to display the lists in that order. The order data is received as an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data consits of string values, then you can sort them like this:

```
responseData.sortWith(
    compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, { it })
)
```

in case of you want sort by spesific value then:

```
responseData.sortWith(
    compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, { it.name })
)
```

It calls a case-insensitive order. With this you can sort uppercase and lowercase characters at the same time. By using

responseData.sortBy { it }

you can't reach the approprite result.

```
Let's say, you have ("Argentina", "an Argentina", "Cloudy Argentina")
The first solution: ("an Argentina", "Argentina", "Cloudy Argentina")
The second solution: ("Argentina", "Cloudy Argentina", "an Argentina")
```

Then just add the sorted data to your recyclerView.